# Revert decreasing integer for progress bar

Tags: delphi, integer, progress-bar

I have an integer. The value is keep decreasing.
I represent it by a progress bar. 
*The result is my progress bar move from right to left.*

e.g:

```
iProgSize := 9999;
iProg := 9998; //( this is going down from time to time to zero);
```

9999 just an example value, this is random.

```
pBar.MaxValue := iProgSize;
pBar.Value := iProg;
```

How to use this kind of value to move the progress bar from left to right ?

Comment: Cant you use bidiMode for this???

Comment: I just checked there is no bidi mode in that control.

Comment: @NasreddineGalfoutthat Yes, was my first attempt, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the position to the bar max value minus the value.

```
pBar.value := iProgSize - iProg;
```

The number processed is equal to the total number to be processed minus the number left to be processed. Processed = Total - Remaining.

If we have 1000 to process, 900 remaining, then 100 have been processed (1000 - 100).

Comment: FWIW, this is extremely simple and trivial math, not even related to programming.

Comment: @JerryDodge sometimes a solution involving simple math is missed when trying to solve a problem.  For an example of almost the same problem on another site : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1231172/Reverse-progress-bar-values

Comment: It is done , @Brian,I need that logical thinking :). Thank you. `pBar.value` the result, `iProgSize` need to life longer, `iProg` was the dynamic variable.